# customize the yammer feeds

Tags: sharepoint-2013, yammer

I am getting the yammer feeds on my page using the following code in content editor webpart.

```
<div id="embedded">
</div>
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script> yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: "#embedded",
            network: network,
            feedType: "group",
            feedId: "all",
            config: {
  header: false ,
  footer: false,    
  }        
            });           
</script>
```

Is there a way to iterate through each of the feeds and customize on how it appears?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. The embedded feed is contained in an iframe, which is under the `yammer.com` domain. It would be very challenging to access those dom elements from your app's domain, due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), let alone to modify them. You may find hacks or work-arounds but they are not trivial tasks to achieve.